# Comparing multiple Mysql Tables to find modified records

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have three tables as a SQLITE3 Dump.

**products,tax,inventory**

From these tables preparing a csv file to import into magento products section. SO that part is over.

Now have to run a daily script which updates the inventory,tax, modified product details(SKU will not change at any case).

In this update section.
  For example, i have 12000 records, in that only may be 400 or 1000 records varied/modified/updated in inventory table,tax table,products table from the last day's Database. The remaining rows will remain same.

So i added the last days tables as  **old_products,old_tax,old_inventory**.

And tried to write sql query to extract only modified records from the two set's of tables

(Note: Both sets of tables available in Same Db.)

***Please can anyone help me how to write a sql query to extract the modified records by comparing two sets of tables.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably change this schema.

I would have a table where I would store the date(s) when I last exported the data to CSV(s):

```
CREATE TABLE CSVLastExported (
  ProductsExportDate datetime,
  TaxExportDate datetime,
  InventoryExportDate datetime
)
```

And I could then have a timestamp column in each of the three tables which would hold the last modification timestamp. I would have a trigger for updating that column.

Querying the modified data for another export would then be as easy as comparing the `LastModified` column against the corresponding column in `CSVLastExported`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
  INNER JOIN CSVLastExport e
    ON p.LastModified > e.ProductsExportDate
```

Answer (score 1):

this gives you all modifications (and the product):

```
 select * from products p inner join old_products o on p.id = o.id
```

and this the modificated products:

```
 select * from products where id in (select id old_products)
```

Comment: It seems to me from how I read the question, the working tables always contain all the rows. They only differ from their `old_` counterparts in that *some* of the rows are modified. And the modified subset is what the OP wants to extract from each of them.

Comment: @andry.. exactly. You are right. Thats what i have to do here. And the old db has 8 tables also new db has 8. So its  difficult for me to write the join queries correctly. Will work it out and post my answer here.